# context menu CSS and event partially working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little issue with my context menu, the CSS doesn't apply and the event on click doesn't work too. If i inspect the element with F12 (on IE 11), I can see the CSS is on the page (in the header) and I can see that all line of the context menu have the event on click but it doesn't work when I click.

CSS :

```
.ctxmenu
{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #F8F8F8; 
    z-index: 11;
    overflow: visible;
}

.ctxline
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #F8F8F8; 
    overflow: visible;
}

.ctxline:hover
{
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

for the constitution of the contextMenu :

```
for (i = 0; i < listCorrection.length; ++i) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    d.appendChild(p);
    p.setAttribute('class', 'ctxline');
    p.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("do something");');
    p.innerText = listCorrection[i];
}
```

when I inspect the element of this context Menu i can see :

```
<p onclick="alert("do something");" class="ctxline">set</p>
```

and the div containing the context Menu :

```
<div id="ctxmenu1" style"CURSOR: pointer" class="ctxmenu">(the p on context menu are here)</div>
```

does anybody have an idea why ? i try to moove it Inside the header with a  but it is still not working.

Comment: Are you nesting double quotes within double quotes in your actual code? `onclick="alert("do something");"`

Comment: well in my JS there is no double quotes around the alert, I try the same code as I give here on a stand alone and it worked fine.

Comment: `ctxmenu { ... }` should be `.ctxmenu { ... }` (missing a ".").  `classe="ctxmenu"` should be `class="ctxmenu"` ("class" is spelt wrong)

Comment: he is there, the copy past f*** me when i copy it here.

Comment: "class" is still spelt wrong so it wont work anyway.

Comment: it is in the result of the inspection, not on the code i write (sorry i'm french so by reflex i wrote it classe instead of class)

Comment: OK. Can you set up a working example on jsfiddle.net showing _all_ of the relevant code?

Comment: Or a snippet here on SO

Comment: i have done a JS fiddle but nothing worked on the fiddle, i don't know why because its the same code as my work (first time i create a JS fiddle and it failed).http://jsfiddle.net/Lugp2x44/2/

Comment: Your jsfiddle works if you include your script in head (No wrap - in head)

Comment: ho Okay, se you can see the final result I'm suposed to get. here the result i got is the list showing of but no style on it, and no action is done when clicking

Comment: Well. It alerts "do something" :)

Comment: :), if only he did the same on my application.

Comment: nop as the text say I am on IE11, but it work in my stand alone but not on my final project

Comment: I have done some more test, my application seems to not even care about any CSS for the ContextMenu only (other CSS work fine), even the positionning of the context Menu isn't working (always show at the top left of my application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after several hours spend on this issue i might have find a fix, if someday someone end up on this page try this :

replace every line that are like this :

```
p.setAttribute('class', 'ctxline');
```

by something like this :

```
p.className = 'ctxline';
```

I know it's the same thing, but well IE so sometimes you have to think outside the box (this fix work for IE11, IE9, I did not test with other Navigator).